# issues in installing opencv

Tags: opencv, cmake, installation

i wanted to compile the Opencv for the first using the following commands

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules \
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

but i am getting the following error

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:128 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/siddhartha/opencv-3.3.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/siddhartha/opencv-3.3.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
(cv) siddhartha@wipro:~/opencv-3.3.0/build$
```

anyone has any idea how to solve this issue .

Comment: can you use the CMake GUI and choose a compiler you have installed?

Comment: Do you have a compiler installed?